# Фиксированный размер таблицы в браузере?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Привет всем! Есть панель администрирования и сайт, написанные на PHP. Помогите реализовать фиксированный размер `table` для отображения в браузере средствами HTML или PHP или JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте CSS:

```
table-layout: fixed
```

Comment: а с полосой прокрутки как-то можно реализовать?

Comment: вложите таблицу в див с `overflow:auto`.